# Can I directly extract contents of a tweet using google sheet formulas?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, twitter, google-sheets-formula

B20 is the cell containing the link to the tweet. So I have a Google sheet with links to tweets and I wanna use formula to extract text of tweet to sheet.

`=INDEX(IMPORTXML(B20,”//a[@Class=‘Css-4rbku5 etc etc’]”),1)`

So I used this sorta command to get the headline of reddit threads, I was hoping similarly Tweets’  content, the text can b extracted as well. But I keep getting error “Imported Content is Empty”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Twitter is dynamically generated

This means that the HTML that is loaded when you request the HTML does not contain any tweets. Once the basic HTML has loaded, then the tweets begin to get populated into the page via JavaScript.

Since this is the case, any HTML you recieve from `IMPORTXML` will not have any tweets. Twitter itself tries to limit any scraping that is not done via the API.

So unfortunately your best recourse is to either use the API (it has a free tier), or learn to use some web automation software such as Puppeteer, which can emulate a person who visits the site, waits for a second to let the content load, and *then* scrape the data.

Disclaimer: It is possible that IMPORTXML will work using the css class as you have done, though this will be very unreliable. The CSS classes are also auto generated, so they will be changing very often.

#### Demonstration

Using `curl` on the command line to fetch the raw HTML of https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/1380306486962782208 (before any JavaScript changes):

```
curl https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/1380306486962782208 >> twitter.html
```

Examining the resulting `twitter.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0,viewport-fit=cover" />
   <link rel="preconnect" href="//abs.twimg.com" />
   <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//abs.twimg.com" />
   <link rel="preconnect" href="//api.twitter.com" />
   <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//api.twitter.com" />
   <link rel="preconnect" href="//pbs.twimg.com" />
   <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//pbs.twimg.com" />
   <link rel="preconnect" href="//t.co" />
   <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//t.co" />
   <link rel="preconnect" href="//video.twimg.com" />
   <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//video.twimg.com" />
   <link rel="preload" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/client-web-legacy/polyfills.98da7185.js" nonce="MjE5MTk0YTItNjQxMy00NzhjLWE0ZWEtNTA0NzEwMzdkNmQy" />
   <link rel="preload" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/client-web-legacy/vendors~main.6fa4fac5.js" nonce="MjE5MTk0YTItNjQxMy00NzhjLWE0ZWEtNTA0NzEwMzdkNmQy" />
   <link rel="preload" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/client-web-legacy/i18n/en.2eb8dfe5.js" nonce="MjE5MTk0YTItNjQxMy00NzhjLWE0ZWEtNTA0NzEwMzdkNmQy" />
   <link rel="preload" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/client-web-legacy/main.88d8e8e5.js" nonce="MjE5MTk0YTItNjQxMy00NzhjLWE0ZWEtNTA0NzEwMzdkNmQy" />
   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="2231777543" />
   <meta property="og:site_name" content="Twitter" />
   <meta name="google-site-verification" content="acYOOcR5z6puMzLn6hLDZI1nNHXPxt57OIstz1vnCV0" />
   <meta name="facebook-domain-verification" content="x6sdcc8b5ju3bh8nbm59eswogvg6t1" />
   <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" crossOrigin="use-credentials" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=en" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ar" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=ar" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ar-x-fm" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=ar-x-fm" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="bg" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=bg" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="bn" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=bn" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ca" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=ca" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="cs" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=cs" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="da" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=da" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=de" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="el" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=el" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=en-GB" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-ss" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=en-ss" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-xx" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=en-xx" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=es" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="eu" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=eu" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fa" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=fa" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fi" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=fi" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fil" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=fil" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=fr" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ga" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=ga" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="gl" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=gl" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="gu" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=gu" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="he" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=he" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="hi" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=hi" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="hr" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=hr" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="hu" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=hu" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="id" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=id" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="it" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=it" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=ja" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="kn" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=kn" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ko" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=ko" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="mr" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=mr" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ms" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=ms" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="nb" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=nb" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=nl" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="pl" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=pl" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="pt" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=pt" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ro" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=ro" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=ru" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="sk" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=sk" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="sr" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=sr" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="sv" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=sv" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ta" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=ta" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="th" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=th" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="tr" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=tr" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="uk" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=uk" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ur" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=ur" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="vi" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=vi" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=zh" />
   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-Hant" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208?lang=zh-Hant" />
   <link rel="canonical" href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/1380306486962782208" />
   <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="/opensearch.xml" title="Twitter">
   <link rel="mask-icon" sizes="any" href="https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/client-web-legacy/icon-svg.168b89d5.svg" color="#1da1f2">
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//abs.twimg.com/favicons/twitter.ico" type="image/x-icon">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="192x192" href="https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/client-web-legacy/icon-ios.b1fc7275.png" />
   <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Twitter" />
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="white" />
   <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />
   <meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="Apir4chqTX+4eFxKD+ErQlKRB/VtZ/dvnLfd9Y9Nenl5r1xJcf81alryTHYQiuUlz9Q49MqGXqyaiSmqWzHUqQwAAABneyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL3R3aXR0ZXIuY29tOjQ0MyIsImZlYXR1cmUiOiJDb250YWN0c01hbmFnZXIiLCJleHBpcnkiOjE1NzUwMzUyODMsImlzU3ViZG9tYWluIjp0cnVlfQ==" />
   <style>html,body{height: 100%;}</style>
   <style id="react-native-stylesheet">[stylesheet-group="0"]{}
      html{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);}
      body{margin:0;}
      button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0;}
      input::-webkit-inner-spin-button,input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,input::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input::-webkit-search-decoration,input::-webkit-search-results-button,input::-webkit-search-results-decoration{display:none;}
      [stylesheet-group="0.1"]{}
      :focus:not([data-focusvisible-polyfill]){outline: none;}
      [stylesheet-group="1"]{}
      .css-1dbjc4n{-ms-flex-align:stretch;-ms-flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-negative:0;-ms-flex-preferred-size:auto;-webkit-align-items:stretch;-webkit-box-align:stretch;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-flex-basis:auto;-webkit-flex-direction:column;-webkit-flex-shrink:0;align-items:stretch;border:0 solid black;box-sizing:border-box;display:-webkit-box;display:-moz-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:-webkit-flex;display:flex;flex-basis:auto;flex-direction:column;flex-shrink:0;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-top:0px;min-height:0px;min-width:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:0px;position:relative;z-index:0;}
      .css-901oao{border:0 solid black;box-sizing:border-box;color:rgba(0,0,0,1.00);display:inline;font:14px -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:0px;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word;}
      .css-16my406{color:inherit;font:inherit;white-space:inherit;}
      [stylesheet-group="2"]{}
      .r-13awgt0{-ms-flex:1 1 0%;-webkit-flex:1;flex:1;}
      .r-4qtqp9{display:inline-block;}
      .r-ywje51{margin-bottom:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:auto;}
      .r-hvic4v{display:none;}
      .r-1adg3ll{display:block;}
      [stylesheet-group="2.2"]{}
      .r-12vffkv>*{pointer-events:auto;}
      .r-12vffkv{pointer-events:none!important;}
      .r-14lw9ot{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00);}
      .r-1p0dtai{bottom:0px;}
      .r-1d2f490{left:0px;}
      .r-1xcajam{position:fixed;}
      .r-zchlnj{right:0px;}
      .r-ipm5af{top:0px;}
      .r-yyyyoo{fill:currentcolor;}
      .r-1xvli5t{height:1.25em;}
      .r-dnmrzs{max-width:100%;}
      .r-bnwqim{position:relative;}
      .r-1plcrui{vertical-align:text-bottom;}
      .r-lrvibr{-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none;user-select:none;}
      .r-13gxpu9{color:rgba(29,161,242,1.00);}
      .r-wy61xf{height:72px;}
      .r-u8s1d{position:absolute;}
      .r-1blnp2b{width:72px;}
      .r-1ykxob0{top:60%;}
      .r-1b2b6em{line-height:2em;}
      .r-q4m81j{text-align:center;}
   </style>
   <body style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
      <noscript>
         <style>
            body {
            -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            overscroll-behavior-y: none;
            }
            .errorContainer {
            background-color: #FFF;
            color: #0F1419;
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 10%;
            font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            }
            .errorButton {
            margin: 3em 0;
            }
            .errorButton a {
            background: #1DA1F2;
            border-radius: 2.5em;
            color: white;
            padding: 1em 2em;
            text-decoration: none;
            }
            .errorButton a:hover,
            .errorButton a:focus {
            background: rgb(26, 145, 218);
            }
            .errorFooter {
            color: #657786;
            font-size: 80%;
            line-height: 1.5;
            padding: 1em 0;
            }
            .errorFooter a,
            .errorFooter a:visited {
            color: #657786;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding-right: 1em;
            }
            .errorFooter a:hover,
            .errorFooter a:active {
            text-decoration: underline;
            }
            #placeholder,
            #react-root {
            display: none !important;
            }
            body {
            background-color: #FFF !important;
            }
         </style>
         <div class="errorContainer">
            <img width="46" height="38" srcset="https://abs.twimg.com/errors/logo46x38.png 1x, https://abs.twimg.com/errors/logo46x38@2x.png 2x" src="https://abs.twimg.com/errors/logo46x38.png" alt="Twitter" />
            <h1>JavaScript is not available.</h1>
            <p>We’ve detected that JavaScript is disabled in this browser. Please enable JavaScript or switch to a supported browser to continue using twitter.com. You can see a list of supported browsers in our Help Center.</p>
            <p class="errorButton"><a href="https://help.twitter.com/using-twitter/twitter-supported-browsers">Help Center</a></p>
            <p class="errorFooter">
               <a href="https://twitter.com/tos">Terms of Service</a>
               <a href="https://twitter.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
               <a href="https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170514">Cookie Policy</a>
               <a href="https://legal.twitter.com/imprint">Imprint</a>
               <a href="https://business.twitter.com/en/help/troubleshooting/how-twitter-ads-work.html">Ads info</a>
               © 2021 Twitter, Inc.
            </p>
         </div>
      </noscript>
      <div id="react-root" style="height:100%;display:flex;">
         <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-13awgt0 r-12vffkv">
            <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-13awgt0 r-12vffkv">
               <style>
                  @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
                  #placeholder {
                  background-color: #000000
                  }
                  }
               </style>
               <div aria-label="Loading…" class="css-1dbjc4n r-14lw9ot r-1p0dtai r-1d2f490 r-1xcajam r-zchlnj r-ipm5af" id="placeholder">
                  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="r-1p0dtai r-13gxpu9 r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-wy61xf r-1d2f490 r-ywje51 r-dnmrzs r-u8s1d r-zchlnj r-1plcrui r-ipm5af r-lrvibr r-1blnp2b">
                     <g>
                        <path d="M23.643 4.937c-.835.37-1.732.62-2.675.733.962-.576 1.7-1.49 2.048-2.578-.9.534-1.897.922-2.958 1.13-.85-.904-2.06-1.47-3.4-1.47-2.572 0-4.658 2.086-4.658 4.66 0 .364.042.718.12 1.06-3.873-.195-7.304-2.05-9.602-4.868-.4.69-.63 1.49-.63 2.342 0 1.616.823 3.043 2.072 3.878-.764-.025-1.482-.234-2.11-.583v.06c0 2.257 1.605 4.14 3.737 4.568-.392.106-.803.162-1.227.162-.3 0-.593-.028-.877-.082.593 1.85 2.313 3.198 4.352 3.234-1.595 1.25-3.604 1.995-5.786 1.995-.376 0-.747-.022-1.112-.065 2.062 1.323 4.51 2.093 7.14 2.093 8.57 0 13.255-7.098 13.255-13.254 0-.2-.005-.402-.014-.602.91-.658 1.7-1.477 2.323-2.41z"></path>
                     </g>
                  </svg>
               </div>
               <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-hvic4v r-1d2f490 r-1xcajam r-zchlnj r-1ykxob0" id="ScriptLoadFailure">
                  <form action="" method="GET">
                     <div dir="auto" class="css-901oao r-1adg3ll r-1b2b6em r-q4m81j"><span class="css-901oao css-16my406">Something went wrong, but don’t fret — let’s give it another shot.</span><br/><input type="hidden" name="failedScript" value=""/><input type="submit" value="Try again"/></div>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

... its too long to paste the whole thing on Stack Overflow...
```

The tweet at this page is:

[image]

But in the whole HTML, this text is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Yeah I had a hunch apis would b required. Appreciate the Explanation too. Very helpful 