# Import data table from webpage to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

This formula, `=IMPORTHTML("https://www.krungsriasset.com/TH/NAV.html", "table", 1)`
works well.

But I can't import data tables using this formula, `=IMPORTHTML("https://www.scbam.com/th/fund/nav/", "table", 1)` from this webpage, `https://www.scbam.com/th/fund/nav/`.

What should be done more ?

Comment: See this answer for more details - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67056410/10445017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS elements cant be **scraped** with google sheets. by disabling them you are left only with:

[image]